# Updating first available row with multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server

I'm having trouble updating the first available row where a specific column is NULL and another column is 2.

```
ID     UserID    Model
1      124       2
2      125       1
3      126       1
4      NULL      3
5      NULL      2
5      NULL      2
```

I can update the first available row, which would be where ID is 4, with an UserID but once I add an additional condition like `AND Model = '2' the query returns 0 row(s) affected.

This is the query I made and am trying to use:

```
UPDATE Table SET UserID = '127'
WHERE UserID IS NULL AND Model = '2'
AND ID IN (SELECT top 1 ID FROM Table where UserID IS NULL) /*Update only 1 row
```

If I remove `AND Model = '2'` it still updates the first available row, but I'm working with a quite large table and would like to specify to only update it if the Model is 2 as well.

Comment: What records are you trying to update?  Are you trying to update the first `ID` where the model is `2`?

Comment: @Siyual I am trying to update the UserID column only if the Model column has the value 2, but it's important that only one row is updated instead of all that meet those conditions.

Comment: Why not using limit ?  UPDATE Table SET UserID = '127'
WHERE UserID IS NULL AND Model = '2' limit 1;

Comment: `LIMIT` is a `MySQL` keyword, this is tagged `SQL Server`.

Comment: @mannu for start sqlserver doesnt have `LIMIT`, instead you have to use `TOP`

Comment: @Mannu I would, but SQL Server 2012 doesn't have "LIMIT"! We have to do it with TOP from what I learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

> TOP (1)

into your criteria while updating

**Example:**

```
UPDATE Table SET UserID = '127'
WHERE UserID IS NULL AND Model = '2'
AND ID = (select top(1) id from category WHERE UserID IS NULL AND Model = '2')
```

Comment: I was missing the second ''AND Model = '2' " in the SELECT. Thanks

Comment: Glad for helping you

Comment: This cant be right, At least you need some `ORDER BY` otherwise `TOP 1` will be random

Answer (score 2):

[Sql Fiddle](http://rextester.com/ZNAPV96282)

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT *
           , row_number() over (partition by [UserID] order by [ID]) as rn
    FROM Table1  
    WHERE Model = 2
      AND UserID IS NULL
)
UPDATE cte
SET [UserID] = 'Updated'
WHERE rn =1;

SELECT *
FROM Table1
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a windowed function to determine the first record in the resultset, and update just the first entry:

```
;With ToUpdate As
(
    Select  *,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By Model Order By Id) As RN
    From    Table
    Where   UserId Is Null
)
Update  ToUpdate
Set     UserId = 127
Where   Model = 2
And     RN = 1
```